# Is this kind of menu possible OOTB?

Tags: navigation

I wonder if this kind of menu possible in SharePoint 2010 OOTB (Without code). I want this menu showing in all sites and subsites in a site collection. I dont want pages, libraries or anything else showing up in the menu, but only the site hierarchy.If it is not possible OOTB, Otherwise i will try to develop some custom ascx control containing an aspmenu to place in masterpage.

[sample menu screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img253/965/menuxj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at this article. [Customizing SharePoint 2010 global navigation with Css and jQuery](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2/) or this one [Customizing the SharePoint 2010 Menu with CSS and jQuery](http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/microsoft-solutions/customizing-the-sharepoint-2010-menu-with-css-and-jquery/)
Also, if you google jquery menu you will find lots of free nice looking menus you can customize.

Add the code to your masterpage and you should be good.

Comment: Actually i was not talking about UI or styling. I am wondering if it is possible to show site hierarchy on the menu.

Comment: Did you try the Global Navigation -> show subsites ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25257/how-to-enable-sub-menu-on-the-global-menu/25262#25262) article could help.

Modify your masterpage, find the SharePoint:AspMenu tag and set the [MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/2cdy75y0)="1" to something larger then 1

Also set the Global Navigation to show sub sites

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer i got progress with using MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels=X but the thing is, i dont want searh sites or other built-in sites showing up in the menu, i only want the hieararchy of the sites i created. can i have something like a filter, for which sites to be displayed?

Comment: Sounds like you need to write your own Custom Navigation Provider